# Android Navigation Component - Navigation to additional activity if user not logged in

Tags: java, android, android-navigation

I currently have an Android project that uses a single activity. This activity (MainActivity) includes a toolbar, a bottom navigation and the nav_host_fragment.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFFFFF" />

<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph"
    android:layout_above="@id/bottom_nav"
    android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"/>

<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_nav"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav"
    />
```

The Main activity loads the first bottom tab (the Home fragment) by default:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    FragmentManager supportFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    NavHostFragment navHostFragment = (NavHostFragment) supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    NavController navController = navHostFragment.getNavController();

    AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(R.id.homeFragment, R.id.secondFragment, R.id.thirdFragment, R.id.fourthFragment).build();
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(toolbar, navController, appBarConfiguration);

    BottomNavigationView bottomNav = findViewById(R.id.bottom_nav);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(bottomNav, navController);
}
```

However, I'd like to make a check to see if the user is signed in or not. If the user is not signed in, I don't want the Home fragment to load, instead I want to navigate to a separate activity with a welcome screen.

I have tried adding the following on the home Fragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);


    SharedPreferences getSharedData = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("MyApp", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Boolean loggedIn = getSharedData.getBoolean("isUserLoggedIn", false);

    if (!loggedIn) {
        Navigation.findNavController(v).navigate(R.id.welcomeActivity);
    }

    // .. load the data for the home screen ..

}
```

However, this causes an error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: View android.widget.LinearLayout{a81e94f V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0} does not have a NavController set
```

How can I navigate to a separate welcome screen if the user is not logged in?

**UPDATE:**

This is the current nav_graph:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
app:startDestination="@id/homeFragment">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/homeFragment"
    android:name="com.myapp.app.HomeFragment"
    android:label="Home"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home">
     // .. actions to sub fragments ..
</fragment>
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/secondFragment"
    android:name="com.myapp.app.SecondFragment"
    android:label="Second"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_second" />
    // .. actions to sub fragments ..
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/thirdFragment"
    android:name="com.myapp.app.ThirdFragment"
    android:label="Third"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_third">
    // .. actions to sub fragments ..
</fragment>
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fourthFragment"
    android:name="com.myapp.app.FourthFragment"
    android:label="Fourth"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_fourth" >
    // .. actions to sub fragments ..
</fragment>

// .. More subfragments linked from the first four ..

<activity
    android:id="@+id/welcomeActivity"
    android:name="com.myapp.app.WelcomeActivity"
    android:label="activity_welcome"
    tools:layout="@layout/activity_welcome" />
</navigation>
```

Home, Second, Third and Fourth are the four tabs at the bottom. What I need is to check if the user is logged in and show the home fragment with the bottom navigation. If the user is not logged in I need to show a separate fragment or activity without the bottom navigation which will link to sign in and sign up options and eventually return to the Home fragment with bottom navigation.

Comment: According to the error, your fragment `LinearLayout` does not have any `NavController` linked with it. Can you share the fragment XML and nav graph?

Comment: @Anand I've added the nav graph and explained a little more what I'm trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling activity as you told separate activity,not fragment. So you have to call intent like this way.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, welcomeActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Hope it will work.

Comment: Activity transition can also be done using the Navigation component. See https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-migrate#add

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good approach to start `WelcomeActivity` while loading `HomeFragment`,
You can check in the `SplashScreen`, if the user not logged in or the user was opened the first time you can show `WelcomeActivity` otherwise you can create `WelcomeFragement` who has the same functionality like `WelcomeActivity`, show `WelcomeFragment` instead of showing `HomeFragment`.

Ex.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //Other stuff.
    SharedPreferences getSharedData = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("MyApp", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Boolean loggedIn = getSharedData.getBoolean("isUserLoggedIn", false);

    if (!loggedIn) 
    {
       //Start WelComeActivity
    }
    else
    {
       //Start MainActivity
    }
}
```

This is just an example or idea you can modify and improve.

**Update**
You can use the nav controller from the Activity, not null condition help to prevent crashes.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{

View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);


SharedPreferences getSharedData = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("MyApp", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Boolean loggedIn = getSharedData.getBoolean("isUserLoggedIn", false);

if (!loggedIn) {

    NavHostFragment navHostFragment = (NavHostFragment) (getActivity() AppCompactActivity).getSupportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    NavController navController = navHostFragment.getNavController();
    navcontroller.navigate(actionForNavigatingHomeFragmentToMainActivity);
 }

}
```

Add action in the welcome activity use popUpTo.
popUpTo and popUpToInclusive still remove destinations from the back stack just as though you had navigated using an ID.

Comment: I've just added the current nav graph and explained a little more what I'm after. My biggest concern is where(in which activity/fragment) would I put the conditional and also, after signing in, how I would return to the home fragment.

Comment: Please check the new update, may help you.

Answer (score 0):

In the home fragment, try changing the below line

```
Navigation.findNavController(v).navigate(R.id.welcomeActivity);
```

to

```
NavHostFragment.findNavController(this).navigate(R.id.welcomeActivity);
```

***As per source code documentation***

`Navigation.findNavController(view)`

```
 /**
 * Find a {@link NavController} given a local {@link View}.
 *
 * <p>This method will locate the {@link NavController} associated with this view.
 * This is automatically populated for views that are managed by a {@link NavHost}
 * and is intended for use by various {@link android.view.View.OnClickListener listener}
 * interfaces.</p>
 *
 * @param view the view to search from
 * @return the locally scoped {@link NavController} to the given view
 * @throws IllegalStateException if the given view does not correspond with a
 * {@link NavHost} or is not within a NavHost.
 */
@NonNull
public static NavController findNavController(@NonNull View view) {
    NavController navController = findViewNavController(view);
    if (navController == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("View " + view + " does not have a NavController set");
    }
    return navController;
}
```

In your case, you are trying to access the view in the [onCreateView](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment#onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20android.os.Bundle)) method, and in this instance of execution, your view for the fragment is still in the process of creation. You are trying to use this view to get the `NavController`. Hence, it is throwing `IllegalStateException`.

In the official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment#onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20android.os.Bundle)) of the method, it is quoted that

> It is recommended to only inflate the layout in this method and move logic that operates on the returned View to onViewCreated(View, Bundle).

I would suggest you also follow the same.

Now, source code documentation for `NavHostFragment.findNavController(this)` is

```
/**
 * Find a {@link NavController} given a local {@link Fragment}.
 *
 * <p>This method will locate the {@link NavController} associated with this Fragment,
 * looking first for a {@link NavHostFragment} along the given Fragment's parent chain.
 * If a {@link NavController} is not found, this method will look for one along this
 * Fragment's {@link Fragment#getView() view hierarchy} as specified by
 * {@link Navigation#findNavController(View)}.</p>
 *
 * @param fragment the locally scoped Fragment for navigation
 * @return the locally scoped {@link NavController} for navigating from this {@link Fragment}
 * @throws IllegalStateException if the given Fragment does not correspond with a
 * {@link NavHost} or is not within a NavHost.
 */
@NonNull
public static NavController findNavController(@NonNull Fragment fragment) {
    // some code here
}
```

According to this, it is taking `fragment` and looking for `NavHostFragment` from its parent and then get the `NavController`.

With this, I believe you can decide which method to use for your navigation. Again, I would suggest you move all your logical code away from the `onCreateView`.